# Jolt Conditional Based on Field

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I want to make a conditional check on a field. Is there any operator which give us to make conditional check on a field in JOLT ?

Input:

```
{
  "a" : "aValue",
  "b" : "bValue,
  "c" : "cValue"
}
```

Output:

if c field exists, output should be

```
{
  "b" : "cValue"
}
```

if c field does not exists, output should be

```
{
  "a" : "aValue",
  "b" : "bValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      // If c does not exists add the c with default value as null
      "c": "null"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "b": "b",
      "c": {
        "null": {
          "@(2,a)": "a"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

[ { "operation": "modify-default-beta", "spec": { // If c does not exists add the c with default value as null "c": "null" } }, { "operation": "shift", "spec": { "c": "b", "b": { "null": { "@(2,a)": "a" } } } } ]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).